# How does calc() work when it contains percentages?

Tags: html, css

I recently ran into some unexpected behavior while designing a site layout.  I was surprised to find that the behavior of `calc()` seems to totally change depending whether there is a percentage based unit anywhere inside its argument.

Here is a minimal reproduction.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid purple .1em;
}

.inner {
  border: solid orange .1em;
}

.inner.em   { width: 3em; }
.inner.calc { width: calc(3em + 0%); }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner em">abc</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner calc">abc</div>
</div>
```

The second one is surprising to me, because I would expect that `calc(3em + 0%)` would be identical to `3em`.  However, every browser I've tested exhibits this behavior.  This behavior occurs with any percentage.  `0%` is not special.  Is this part of the css spec?

Comment: I would use 0% to illustrate my point with the least possible code, although it happens with any percentage value.

Comment: Yeah, I updated my question to clarify.

Comment: Cool man...checking MDN but nothing so far.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a 'loop' type thing. The inner width will determine the width of the parent....but the width of the inner is based on the parent. Therefore the parent width 'falls back' on the only width can be sure of...the content.

Comment: I believe @Paulie_D 's comment to be the closest to the true. See that behavior when setting the calc to percentage minus something. The parent's boundaries fits what was *supposed to be* the child's width, but doesn't match the evaluated value: http://jsfiddle.net/hqhg1bnu/1/

Answer (score 8):

The [specs for calc](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#calc-computed-value) explicitly say that it's not resolved completely at that time:

> Where percentages are not resolved at computed value, they are not
>   resolved in ‘calc()’ expressions, e.g. ‘calc(100% - 100% + 1em)’
>   resolves to ‘calc(0% + 1em)’, not to ‘calc(1em)’. If there are special
>   rules for computing percentages in a value (e.g. the ‘height’
>   property), they apply whenever a ‘calc()’ expression contains
>   percentages.

I would tentatively speculate that 10.2:

> If the containing block's width depends on this element's width, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

applies here, since there is a percentage involved, so just as with a `width:150%` for the inner block, the outer block uses shrink-to-fit.

Comment: This is relevant, but it doesn't seem to completely answer the question, because this part of the spec doesn't say how `calc(0% + 1em)` is ultimately computed as a physical dimension.

Comment: @recursive: yes, I'm trying to wrap my head around 10.3 right now

Comment: Aha!  "Undefined behavior".  It's a little surprising that there is consistency across so many browsers in behavior for this.  I'm a little disappointed, but it's not unreasonable.